# Export UV Layout in proportion to object size, not UV map

Tags: uv-image-editor

When I unwrap an object, the UV Map automatically expands to fit the layout size, 1024 x 1024. Is there a way to unwrap it in proportion to the object size, and not the UV layout size? I need both of the maps to be the same height in pixels when working with them in Photoshop.

This one expands horizontally:

[image]

This one expands vertically:

[image]

Which is throwing off the texture proportions in PhotoShop. I don't want to resize the image.

[image]

Edit: Here's the UV Layout with all three panels joined and unwrapped per answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unwrap both meshes together. (If they are 2 separate Objects then Join them temporarily.)

When both are unwrapped to the same UV space then you will have to do a little editing to get them both aligned.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I hate the idea of moving or resizing the maps (or are they called islands?), but I went ahead and just joined all three (I had two wider panels than the other) and they unwrapped stacked vertically, which is taller than they are wide, so they are all now the same height. Then I just divided the texture images height by 3 and that's precise enough.I can't believe there aren't numeric controls in the UV Editor. My end goal was to have the wood grain a consistent size and resolution.